# How to run a new process with python multiprocessing each time a condition is met, and up to a maximum number of processes?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, process, multiprocessing, pool

I have a multiprocessed code that performs the following:

1. Parse a series of huge files line by line
2. Add lines to a list as long as a condition is met
3. When condition is `False`, `apply_async()` a function to the list, in a `Pool()`

```
def main_function(func_args):
    [...]
    # some heavy calculations 
    # queue is among the func_args
    queue.put(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    manager = mp.Manager()
    lock = manager.Lock()
    queue = manager.Queue()
    pool = manager.Pool(processes=20, maxtasksperchild=20)

    for line in open(infile, "r"):
        if condition == True:
            # fill list
        elif condition == False:
            pool.apply_async(target=main_function, args=func_args)
    else:
        # run last list before closing file 
        pool.apply_async(target=main_function, args=func_args)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Now, the code works *per se*, but I noticed a couple of things:

- Until all the 20 first processes are over, no new 20 are spawned. Am I doing the `apply_async` correctly?
- The memory usage is pretty high even with a small subset of data: does each process generate a "personal" copy of the arguments that goes into the memory, unless I share it with `Manager()`?

What I'm after, is:

- I would like each process to be run as soon as possible, and up to 20 at once (the 20 is passed by command line from the user via `argparse`)

Any advice from more expert people?  :)